# taking a list as a sample out of .r file

Tags: r, list, sample

I am trying to take some data out of a .r file.I am using R studios.The data I am trying to get out is actually a list.e.g,
from the following file,

```
"light" <- 
 list("1879" = c(850., 740., 900., 1070., 930., 850., 950., 980., 980., 880., 1000., 980.,
930., 650., 760., 810., 1000., 1000., 960., 960., 960., 940., 960.,
940., 880., 800., 850., 880., 900., 840., 830., 790., 810., 880., 880.,
830., 800., 790., 760., 800., 880., 880., 880., 860., 720., 720., 620.,
860., 970., 950., 880., 910., 850., 870., 840., 840., 850., 840., 840.,
840., 890., 810., 810., 820., 800., 770., 760., 740., 750., 760., 910.,
920., 890., 860., 880., 720., 840., 850., 850., 780., 890., 840., 780.,
810., 760., 810., 790., 810., 820., 850., 870., 870., 810., 740., 810.,
940., 950., 800., 810., 870.)
 , "1882" = c(883., 816., 778., 796., 682., 711., 611., 599., 1051., 781., 578., 796.,
774., 820., 772., 696., 573., 748., 748., 797., 851., 809., 723.)
 )
```

I want to take the 1879 data out of it as a sample,I have tried

```
light=source("/Users/me/Desktop/light.r")
attach(light)
datasample1879=sample(light[1879],100)
```

but it gives me an error that that "Error in numeric(n) : invalid 'length' argument"
 and if i type

```
light[1879]
```

it gives me

```
$<NA>
NULL
```

Can someone please help me in this...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `sample(light[['1879']],100)` or `sample(light$'1879', 100)`.

Comment: yes tried, but didn't work. thanks though.

Comment: I didn't find any problems while sourcing too.

Comment: Could you run it on R console and see if it works

Comment: thanks man, i will try something but i am doing the same thing and its not working, i am using r studios on mac but i think that should not be the problem,may be i should restart  r studios.Thanks for your help dude,at least now i know that there is nothing wrong with the code but there is some error else where. thanks @ akrun

Comment: You don't have to create an object `light` again nor attach it.  From the example, the `light` object is already in the `.R` file. So, simply `source(light.R)` and sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
source('light.R')
sample(light[['1879']], 100)
#[1]  910  870  720  870  810  890  900  850  800  770 1070  860  880  850  810
#[16]  760  840  740  980  840  740  760  960  980  810  870  860  880  860  810
#[31]  760  790  960  910  880  870  880  810 1000  950  720  940  760 1000  740
#[46]  790  840  830  880  620  980  760  650  820  920  840  800  850  950  850
#[61]  890  850  750  880  810  850  800  850  800  810  840  890  840  930  720
#[76] 1000  960  950  940  780  790  810  810  840  940  830  880  850  840  810
#[91]  880  960  880  970  900  820  800  780  930  880
```

Comment: I have tried both ways but it give me an error that
 
    Error in numeric(n) : invalid 'length' argument

somehow it is telling me that the data is not numeric. Thanks anyway for helping @akrun .

Comment: @BlackSwan Let me try to source it.

Comment: This should work though... OP, are you using the `sample` function from the base package? Can you try `base::sample([['1879']], 100)`? And definitely stop using `attach`.